# How can I open a SQL Server Template without using my mouse?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, ssms

In Sql Server Management Studio 2016, I can open the Template Browser with the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>.  But then I need to click on the template browser to activate it before typing to select folders and files.  Is there any way to activate the template browser without clicking?  This worked automatically in an earlier version I had (SSMS 2008?).
[screenshot of SSMS Template Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5qjT.png)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible in SSMS 2017 either. I think you can report bugs at [connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback).